# If $a,a+1, a+2,…a+n$ are composite then prove $a^t, a^t+1, a^t+2,…a^t+n$ are also composite for some $t$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math

We are given two positive integers $a>2$ and $n$ such that the following $n+1$ numbers are all composite numbers: $$a,a+1, a+2,…a+n$$
Prove that there exists an integer $t>1$ such that the following consecutive numbers are all composite: $$a^t, a^t+1, a^t+2,…a^t+n$$

I have been unable to think of how to even start with this, so any hints would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint / Thought process:

Fix an index $i$.
We are given that $ a \equiv -i \pmod{p_i}$ for some primes $p_i$.
Can you classify what $\{t_i\}$ would also satisfy $ a^{t_i} \equiv -i \pmod{p_i}$?

Is there a $ t$ that exists in each $ \{t_i \}$?
If yes, we are done.

Answer (score 0):

Proof sketch:

Notice that we only care about the $k$'s such that $\gcd(k,a)=1$. Also by Euler's theorem, for any $M$ that is coprime with $a$, there exists $t$ such that $M|a^t-a$ (actually $t=\varphi(M)+1$ where $\varphi$ is the Euler's totient function.) Now we can choose $M=\text{lcm}_{k\le n,\gcd(a,k)=1} a+k$ and $t$ be the number such that $M|a^t-a$. So we know that, for $\gcd(k,a)>1$, $a^t+k$ is composite. For $\gcd(a,k)=1$ $a+k|M$, so $a+k|a^t-a$, thus $a+k|a^t-a+a+k$, or $a+k|a^t+k$, which means $a^t+k$ is composite.

We don't use the fact that $a,a+1, a+2,\dots,a+n$ are composite. Just used that they are all greater than $1$ and $a\ge 2$.